# Only One Border for Flex Image Grid Cells via CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border

I have a flexbox grid of images and I'm trying to only add one border to each of the cells — the challenge is that this is a grid that will continue to have images added to it, so I'll never know exactly how many images/cells there will be. I'm trying to accomplish this via CSS alone. My code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
</div>
```

The obvious challenge is to avoid the double borders something like this would inevitably create on the class `.item`:

`border: 1px solid #000;`

And not knowing in advance how many images there will be in the grid means I can't use something like `:nth-of-type(xn)` to remove or add borders. Thanks for any help you can provide here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly hacky, but using a negative left and top `margin` of 1 pixel will cover the double border.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Example image">
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution looks great on my Macbook in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but on my PC, Chrome, Firefox and Edge have multiple instances of double-borders.

Comment: @jimiayler Bizarre. I'm not seeing that issue on Windows in any of those 3 browsers!

Comment: Yeah, hard to show this in these comments, but definitely occuring.

Comment: I edited my question above to show screenshots of those examples.

Comment: @jimiayler Can you confirm your browser zoom level is 100% in those screenshots? It looks like you may be zoomed in (the 150px images are larger than 150px) which does lead to inconsistent border lines on the web.

Comment: Aha! So, this is a client-provided laptop I'm working on and the display resolution was set to 150% — set it back to 100% and we have a winner. Thanks for checking that and for the correct answer.